# Can Algolia support category and/or product level synonyms?

Tags: synonym, algolia

From reviewing the documentation, adding synonyms seems really straight forward.

For my site however, we have such a diverse mix of product categories that we need synonyms to be based on category in some cases.

Example:
A search for "x360" is a synonym for "xobx 360" in the category "game consoles"

A search for "x360" is a model number in the category "laptops"

Therefore we would want the synonym to be activated in the "games consoles" category only.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you described even if the query `x360` matches the synonym `xbox 360` when you are in the category `laptop` (so with the facetFilter="category:laptop") it doesn't matter, because at the end there shouldn't be any record matching with `xbox 360` within that category. So the engine will then pass on other matches and match the query `x360` with one of the laptop reference.